# Identify columns which cause non match between two dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby, pandas-merge

I compare two DataFrames (`df1` and `df2`) each of which shall have unique rows for a given combination of keys. That means there are not duplicates for keys such as `Col1` and `Col2`.

```
import pandas as pd
                        #    OK   NOK   NOK
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Col1': ['A', 'A', 'B'],
                    'Col2': ['J', 'K', 'M'],
                    'Col3': ['1', '2', '3'],
                    'Col4': ['UA', 'RU', 'EU']
                   })
                        #    OK   NOK  NOK single
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Col1': ['A', 'A', 'B', 'C'],
                    'Col2': ['J', 'L', 'N', 'O'],
                    'Col3': ['1', '2', '3', '4'],
                    'Col4': ['UA', 'RU', 'non-EU', 'CN']
                   })

matching_key = ['Col1', 'Col3']
```

Firstly, I *naively* identify which rows are not matching

```
non = df1.merge(df2, indicator=True, how='outer').query('_merge != "both"')
non['_merge'] = (non['_merge'].str.replace('left_only', 'df1').str.replace('right_only', 'df2'))

non = pd.DataFrame({'Col1': ['A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'C'],
                    'Col2': ['K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O'],
                    'Col3': ['2', '2', '3', '3', '4'],
                    'Col4': ['RU', 'RU', 'EU', 'non-EU', 'CN'],
                  '_merge': ['df1', 'df2', 'df1', 'df2', 'df2']
                          })
```

Then I want to find out what column/s cause this mis-match, considering the uniqueness keys (?).

So for instance, to know that `Col2` causes mismatch with keys `Col1 = 'A'` and `Col3 = '2'`, and `[Col2, Col4]` cause mismatch with keys `Col1 = 'B'` and `Col3 = '3'`. Something like

```
result = {['Col2']: pd.DataFrame({'Col1': ['A', 'A'],
                                  'Col3': ['2', '2'],
                                  'Col2': ['K', 'L']
                                  }),
  ['Col2', 'Col4']: pd.DataFrame({'Col1': ['B', 'B'],
                                  'Col3': ['3', '3'],
                                  'Col2': ['M', 'N'],
                                  'Col4': ['EU', 'non-EU']
                                  })
          }
```

---

I am open to any way that helps to quickly get an overview of columns causing mismatch.

One can then tackle issues from least complex (only one column) to more complex (more columns).

Comment: Are you just asking if between df1 and df2 where all the columns are not the same for each row?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Building on the merged DataFrame that you've built, we could use `groupby` + `transform(size)` to create a boolean mask to filter the rows where `matching_key` appears more than once (this is used to filter out keys that exist in only one DataFrame).

Then build a desired dictionary using a `groupby` + dict comprehension where we define the keys as the column names that don't share a value across the two DataFrames (using `nunique`).

```
merged = df1.merge(df2, indicator=True, how='outer').query("_merge!='both'")
tmp = merged[merged.groupby(matching_key)['_merge'].transform('size') > 1].drop(columns='_merge')
out = {tuple(df0.columns[df0.nunique()>1]) : df0 for _, df0 in tmp.groupby(matching_key)}
```

Output:

```
{
 ('Col2',):
 Col1 Col2 Col3 Col4
 1    A    K    2   RU
 3    A    L    2   RU,

 ('Col2', 'Col4'):
 Col1 Col2 Col3    Col4
 2    B    M    3      EU
 4    B    N    3  non-EU
}
```